# How to autocomplete long file names in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal

If I have in current directory a file with a long name starting with "build" I can write in console "build", press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and autocomplete type full filename for me. However if I have multiple files starting with `build` the autocomplete doesn't work - it simply gives me a list of files starting with `build`.

In contrary in Windows pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> key immediately gives to me full file name of the first file and if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key second time it gives me second file name.

How to autocomplete filenames in Linux like in Windows?
PS: Its really terrible if I have several long filenames that differ by extension only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they differ by extension only the autocomplete will autofill all untill there are multiple options. When tabbing yields a list of names, type the next character and hit tab again to resume auto completing.

As I'm linux minded I really have fights with the way windows autocomplete works, guess it's what you're used to ;)

Answer (score 5):

Something that is a life-saver for me is to have bash cycle through the possibilities instead of showing a dumb list.

As bash is using `readline` for its auto-completion, add the following lines to `~/.inputrc`

*Once you're satisfied and have thoroughly tested below solution for a few days/weeks, **cut and paste** (don't copy!) the same settings from `~/.inputrc` to `/etc/inputrc` which contains the system-wide settings, making this available to all users on your system.*

#### The codez:

```
# mappings to have up and down arrow searching through history:
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
# mappings to have left and right arrow go left and right: 
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char

# mapping to have [Tab] and [Shift]+[Tab] to cycle through all the possible completions:
"\t": menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

then `exit` your terminal (or remote terminal like putty) and open it again...

#### Examples:

1. When you have 3 files: `file1`, `file2` and `file3` and you type:

   ```
   e fTabTabTab
   ```

   it'll cycle forwards through:

   ```
   e file1
   e file2
   e file3
   ```

   and when you want to cycle backwards, just hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. When you type:

   ```
   very-complicated-command with lots of command line parameters
   ```

   and next time you need the same command, you just type:

   ```
   very↑
   ```

   and it'll type for you:

   ```
   very-complicated-command with lots of command line parameters
   ```

### This will save you a ton of time in bash!  ;-)

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/607903/344926)

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1) You can type one more letter in and tab again

2) Use a shell with better completions. I use zsh, but fish has amazing (somewhat better) completions as well

For zsh, check out [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

EDIT: At least on the default zsh Config, you need to tab twice before it starts cycling through the options